# ASP.NET Core: Listening on both `https://mydomain` and `https://www.mydomain` with Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to set up an ASP.NET Core web server with Kestrel. I want  Kestrel to listen for all requests coming from both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`, but I can't quite figure out how to do this.

I'm currently using the following code to set up Kestrel in my program start:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<AppStartup>();
            webBuilder.UseUrls(
                "https://example.com:443",
                "http://example.com:80",
                //"https://www.example.com:443",        // This obviously doesn't work with all enabled, 
                //"http://www.example.com:80",          // as it tries to double-bind the ports...
            );
            // Workaround for HTTP2 bug in .NET Core 3.1 and Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
            options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(defaults =>
                defaults.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1
            )
        );
    });
```

I've also tried doing the following in my `AppStartup`, which I really thought was the solution, going off [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1) resource.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseRewriter(opt => opt.AddRedirectToWwwPermanent());
    ...
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. What would be the correct way to do this via Kestrel? Some anticipated questions:

No, I am not running Kestrel behind IIS and have no intention to do so (not really sure why I keep seeing people do this? Should I be doing this? What do I get out of it?)

Thanks so much for reading!

Answer (score 0):

By default, ASP.NET Core binds to:

- http://localhost:5000
- https://localhost:5001 (when a local development certificate is present)

Specify URLs using the:

- ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable.
- --urls command-line argument.
- urls host configuration key.
- UseUrls extension method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration

In launchsettings.json you probably have `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"` which is how it's done during debugging.

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks, but I am not referring to deploying on `localhost`. Rather, I am deploying tp production on a public server with a domain name.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the urls on the command line with --urls ?

Comment: I have not, but was hoping to deal with url assignment on the app configuration level rather than the execution level to fit better into the CI pipeline I am using (where I already have a good system for generating the configuration files it gets the domain from)